# How do I use Console 2 with Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, console

Patience please: this is a `for dummies` question. I've never used a console before and I started to learn Ruby. I use cmd.exe in Windows, but it's bland and has no colour coding, which hurts my eyes.

I did some research and came across this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console

Console 2 is a nice alternative, apparently. I downloaded it, but I doesn't seem to do what I want it to do, and I don't know where to put it. It has no installer. For example, if I type `ruby --version` it tells me `ruby is not a recognized command.` I understand I might have to configure something, but I can't find any relevant documentation, and I don't know where to put the program, or if that matters.

How do I get it to work as a replacement for cmd.exe, or at least recognize my commands like `git version` and `ruby version` etc... ? A "not so technical" explanation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is **not a replacement** for cmd.exe and not an alternative shell, it's just *command-promt window with some makeover*
2. It has the same rules as pure cmd.exe (regarding "... not found" errors), thus - you have to resolve PATH-issues separately
3. Console2 doesn't require any installation (yes, such programs without overbloated installers still exist in wild), just extract archive into any location and start Console.exe

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But if I launch `cmd.exe,` all my commands work normally. If I launch `Console2,` nothing does. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Check PATH in cmd.exe window and in Console2 window 2. Define *by hand* cmd.exe as shell in main console settings (Edit - Settings - Console) and in tabs settings for single "Cmd" tab (Edit - Settings - Tabs)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I had just added a directory to the command path, cmd.exe was picking it up, but not console2 for some reason.  Check your path by typing "path" into both console2 and cmd.exe.  In my case the paths were the same, except for the recently added directory.  I rebooted, tried again, and abracadabra, it works now.

There is a bug already filed:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3520244&group_id=43764&atid=437332